# Exception loading simple GWT view

Tags: java, gwt

I have a simple `entrypoint` class that just loads a Panel

```
    public class TestUI implements EntryPoint
    {
        PanelA panelA = new PanelA();

        public void onModuleLoad()
        {
            final RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();

            rootPanel.add( panelA );
        }
    }
```

Here is PanelB

```
        public class PanelB extends HTMLPanel
    {
        public PanelB()
        {
            super("Panel B");
            final PanelA panelA = new PanelA();
            Button btnNewButton = new Button("Go to panel A");
            btnNewButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    final RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
                    rootPanel.clear();
                    rootPanel.add( panelA );
                }
            });
            add(btnNewButton);
        }

    }
```

and here is panel A

```
        public class PanelA extends HTMLPanel
    {
        public PanelA( )
        {
            super("Panel A");
            final PanelB panelB = new PanelB();
            Button btnNewButton = new Button("Go to panel B");
            btnNewButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    final RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();
                    rootPanel.clear();
                    rootPanel.add( panelB );
                }
            });
            add(btnNewButton);
        }
    }
```

However when I try to load the page containing this entry point it fails with the exception trace below.
If I replace the reference to Panel A in the entrypoint with a plain HTML panel then it loads fine.  What is wrong with my simple panels?
I'm basically trying to create a GUI where I can click back and forth between pages and I figured this would be the first step towards that goal.

```
Exception in thread "Code server for stockwatcher from Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel$RemoteDeathError: Remote connection lost
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:536)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel$ReturnMessage.send(BrowserChannel.java:1310)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:533)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are causing a mutual recursion or cyclic dependency call... Here is the detailed analysis...

In the `TestUI`  you are creating an instance of `PanelA`. **What happen when you create an instance of a class?** *Its constructor gets called*. In this case `PanelA`'s constructor gets called. In there you are creating an instance of `PanelB` and hence `PanelB`'s constructor gets called. Now again in `PanelB` you are creating an instance of `PanelA` and hence its constructor gets called and the process repeats infinitely. A better programming technique should avoid these kind of cyclic dependencies. Avoid this and it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

With every Panel A you are creating, you create a new Panel B, which is itself creating a new Panel A, which is creating a new Panel B, which is infinitely continuing. Maybe that's the problem.
I think you should call the constructor of panel B/panel A only in the onClick-Event.